# Open-source SSH app for iPhone

Tags: ios, terminal, software-recommendation

I don't trust any SSH app on the App Store to make secure connections.

Any clue if there exist open-source terminals for iPhone or iOS?

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.  You can [edit] your question to include any missing info.

Comment: Donno why this is downvoted. Logging in to your server via some Foo company software is never a good idea.

Comment: this was one of my first questions... tbh, new members have a harder time getting upvotes than older members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best ssh client I've used on iOS is [Prompt from Panic Software](https://panic.com/prompt/).

That being said, there are open source ssh clients for iOS, like [Blink Shell](https://github.com/blinksh/blink) which also provides you with a local shell. Blink is available for **free** from iOs [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id1594898306).

Comment: blink shell is not free